# Merge two git repos as part of a migration

Tags: git

Git repo A and repo B need to be merged into new repo C. The target of repo B should be the subfolder /B in C. After the merge, the commit history of C should show the original A and B commits (mixed). The commit history of each individual file should still be intact.

Also, since this is part of a migration, there may be occasional new commits for the original repos A and B. We would like to also copy these commits to C. Is there an elegant way to do this via command line, or do we require a tool?

Comment: Why not merge B into A (or A into B) instead of creating a brand new repo?

Comment: Is there anything of any use here: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=merge+two+git+repos

Comment: A repo could include all the tags and branches. Maybe more. All of that or just the main branch?

Comment: @Guildenstern One branch is enough for the migration, but I can easily add the original repo as additional remote and pull + merge another branch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create a new empty repository 'C'.
2. Make an initial commit because we need one before we do a merge.
3. Add a remote to old repository 'A'.
4. Merge A/master to New/master.
5. Make a subdirectory 'A'.
6. Move all files into subdirectory 'A'.
7. Commit all of the file moves.
8. Repeat 3-6 for 'B'

Please see https://saintgimp.org/2013/01/22/merging-two-git-repositories-into-one-repository-without-losing-file-history/